# jQuery code to print JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

Using jQuery code, how can I print the JSON data?

While printing the `data`, I am getting `[object object]`.

How can I see the actual data using jQuery to convert `[object object]`?

Comment: Are you using it for debugging? If so, use `console.log(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), for browsers like < IE8 which does not support native JSON use a pollyfill like [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: @JanDvorak but the is the jQuery tag, so I think we can safely assume OP is looking for javascript

Comment: I can use jQuery without Javascript: Coffeescript, Dart, Opal and probably more

Comment: @JanDvorak yes... Hopefully that is not the case here :)

Comment: didn't downvote, but I was pinged. Maybe someone does not like any suggestions of remote libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (var jsonObj in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(jsonObj)) {
    alert(jsonObj + " -> " + p[jsonObj]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try VK Beautife http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkbeautify/
It will take json data and print it all out on your screen if you want. Something along the lines of:

```
function HandleHtml(data) {
    $('#divMain').append(vkbeautify.json(data));
}
```